Действие кнопок пока код ждет текст
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c, dp=dp: c.data == 'add_balance' and dp.current_state(user=c.from_user.id).get_state() != 'waiting_for_bet')
async def process_add_balance(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    user_state = await dp.current_state(user=callback_query.from_user.id).get_state()
    if user_state != 'waiting_for_bet':
        instructions_text = "<b>Введите сумму</b>"
        keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton("Назад", callback_data="main_menu"))
        sent_message = await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback_query.from_user.id, message_id=callback_query.message.message_id, text=instructions_text, reply_markup=keyboard, parse_mode='HTML')
        await BetState.waiting_for_bet.set()
        await dp.current_state(user=callback_query.from_user.id).update_data(sent_message_id=sent_message.message_id)

Как сделать так, что бы кнопка действовала в такой ситуации, пока код ждет ответа от пользователя?
